# Why are Lumen environment variables out of date (or mismatched?)

Tags: php, docker, lumen

So for some reason my lumen .env variables, when echoed out on the backend, don't match what I have in the actual file.

for instance, `APP_DEBUG` is set to true in the file but when I echo it out I get false or null. Also, if I try to change the `APP_NAME` nothing happens, it echoes out an outdated value.

I have tried running `php artisan cache:clear` but that doesn't seem to work either. For what it's worth I'm running this in a docker environment, not sure if that would affect things. Also I'm running php 7.3 with Lumen 6.0.

Comment: Are you echoing onto the browser or doing it somewhere else, like Tinker?

Comment: echoing out in browser/postman atm

Comment: If you're using ```php artisan serve``` try stopping it and restarting.

Comment: nope, im using a docker set up with nginx so no need to use the lumen server at all.

Comment: Oh. Cool. Restart the container and see if it changes?

Comment: well the issue was indeed docker related, it turns out some env properties were being defined in docker-compose.yml

Comment: Ah. Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue was indeed docker related.

It turns out that our environment has all .env related properties defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file, which was overwriting stuff. so I just had to change this:

```
environment:
  <<: *environment
  APP_NAME: <old value>
  APP_URL: http://auth.172.17.0.1.nip.io
```

and add APP_DEBUG to it as well as modify APP_NAME. So if anyone else runs into this and you're using docker, make sure that docker isn't overwriting the env properties.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `php artisan config:clear` to flush the cache of the configuration files.

The command `php artisan cache:clear` is to flush the cache of the application.

> If you execute the `config:cache` command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the env function from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been cached, the `.env` file will not be loaded and all calls to the env function will return `null`.

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#configuration-caching

Comment: nope, unfortunately that didn't fix the issue :( still getting outdated values when i echo out env variables....